# If I read from a stream from WebRequest.GetResponseStream am I reading from memory or the network

Tags: c#, ftp, webrequest, buffering

I have the following code that downloads a file from an FTP server:

```
var req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp_addr + file_path);
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(...);
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
using (var strm = resp.GetResponseStream())
using (var mem_strm = new MemoryStream())
{
    //The Web Response stream doesn't support seek, so we have to do a buffered read into a memory stream
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int red_byts = 0;
    do
    {
        red_byts = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        mem_strm.Write(buffer, 0, red_byts);
    }
    while (strm.CanRead && red_byts > 0);

    //Reset the stream to position 0 for reading
    mem_strm.Position = 0;
    //Now I've got a mem stream that I can use
}
```

Since the raw stream returned from "GetResponseStream" cannot be read or sought (cannot perform a seek on it). It seems to me that this code is actually performing a request to the FTP server for the next chunk of the file and copying it into memory. Am I correct, or is the entire response downloaded when you can GetResponseStream?

I just want to know so I can correctly apply awaits with ReadAsync calls in asynchronous methods that make use of FTP downloading. My intuition tells me to change the line:

```
red_byts = strm.Read(...);
```

to

```
red_byts = await strm.ReadAsync(...);
```

The documentation of WebRequest.GetResponseStream doesn't seem to specify, nor does the documentation for FtpWebRequest.GetResponseStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw stream should be a network stream; to verify this, check out `strm.GetType().Name`.

> It seems to me that this code is actually performing a request to the FTP server for the next chunk of the file and copying it into memory. Am I correct, or is the entire response downloaded when you can GetResponseStream?

Neither.

It is *not* sending separate requests for each call to `Read`/`ReadAsync`; rather, there is only one request, and the stream represents the body of the one response.

It is also *not* downloading the entire response before returning from `GetResponseStream`. Rather, the stream represents the download. *Some* buffering is going on - as the server is sending data, the network stack and the BCL are reading it in for you - but there's no guarantee that it's download by the time you *start* reading the stream.

> I just want to know so I can correctly apply awaits with ReadAsync calls in asynchronous methods that make use of FTP downloading. My intuition tells me to [use async]

Yes, you should use asynchronous reads. If some data is already buffered, they may complete synchronously; otherwise, they will need to wait until the server sends more data.